# What is the Semantics of this Notation: admin.auth.UserInfo?

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I am struggling with the docs for Firebase, Google Cloud etc. I notice I often get stuck on this notation. There must be something I do not know about it or have forgotten.

For example this page [admin.auth.UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserInfo) tells me I can get info about the user (email etc). But after reading the page I still don't know how. What am I missing?

PS: I believe I know that `admin` comes from this but it does not help me:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the Admin SDK, to get information about a user, call [admin.auth().getUser(uid)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser).  An example is provided in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).

`getUser()` returns a [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord).  It contains an number of properties, including [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#providerData), which is an array of [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserInfo).

Each client SDK provides methods to obtain the UID of an authorized user.  For example, on Android it's `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` ([example here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)).

The UID of each user for a project is available in the Authorization panel of the Firebase Console.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I have a number of questions. To begin with, where do you get the `uid`?

Comment: I updated my answer.  If you need more information, please explain your use case.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That cleared things up. I was touched by magical thinking and thought the server knew the user. (Since I'm in control of the calls to the server it can't know the user.)

Comment: Maybe it helps someone, in the web browswer client: `let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;`

Comment: So it works. Very nice, thanks. But my big question is how I should have gotten there without your help. I simply do not understand how I am supposed to read the documentation if I start from for example UserInfo. (My temporary confusion about uid is just a byproduct of my real confusion over how to read the docs...)

Comment: Admittedly, there's a lot to take in and stitch together.  I'd suggest starting with the Guildes, for example [this one on Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to going to the Reference docs for more details.  The Guides contain many good examples.  And there are also the [sample projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/).

Comment: Thanks. The doc structure at least begins to make sense now: Guides, reference, samples, lib. And I am less confused over credentials and authorization. However what I am trying to do is to access Cloud Speech Api. I did set up some credentials in `index.js` with Firebase `admin.initializeApp({credential: _, databaseURL: _})`. That does not seem to be enough. So I am looking for the missing piece there.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are reading the documentation of an interface. It defines what UserInfo has.

If you want to access to a method, for example for reading userInfo, first you have to access to auth service using `admin.auth().<method>`.

If you want more info about how to use it, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth

Comment: Yes, but how do you call it? And how do you know that? What is the syntax you should use to get display name? You should of course use `displayName`, but how?